# NodeJs / Регулярные выражения / как заменить все пробелы между кавычками на _

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно заменить все пробелы внутри кавычек на _
например:
а б в "г_д_е"

Comment: Между кавычками - это в строке? Запишите, пожалуйста, значение до преобразования и значение с теми же входными данными после.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Найдите область область в кавычках
2. В этой области (подстроке) замените пробелы на `_`.
3. Замените подстроку

Найти зону между кавычек можно

```
\"[^\"]+\"
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте вот так:

```js
  const str = 'ddd "aa aa 789 " d d d "a a a"'
  const newstr = str.replace(/("[^"]*")/g, (_, match) => match.replace(/ /g, "_"))
  console.log(newstr)
```

Comment: В вашем варианте подвыражение в скобках занимает всю регулярку, так что можно обойтись без скобок и только первым аргументом функции.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty первым аргументом сама исходная строка является, что имеется в виду? Может просто запишете сюда выравжение, мне тоже интересно...

Comment: Судя по [Specifying a function as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) — первый аргумент это подстрока, с которой совпадает вся регулярка, а дальше идут скобки. Строка, в которой заменяют, идёт предпоследним аргументом. Так что, если  не ошибаюсь, достаточно: `str.replace(/"[^"]*"/g, match => match.replace(/ /g, "_"))`

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, верно, это я понял так, что там группа, а тут же как раз подстрока совпадения.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty точно, немного ошибся, спасибо!